# Determine if Linux OS is booting off a USB

Tags: linux, bash

I need to determine (with a bash script) if a Linux OS is booting off a USB. Can we `grep` some command to find out?

Comment: More context. Why are you doing this type of detection?

Comment: @ewwhite install script

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure.

Comment: Not sure this would work in all cases, but you could first check what block device is mounted on / and then try to look up `/sys/block/sdX/device/model`. For me it says 'USB Flash Drive' for a USB stick. YMMV though.

Comment: Seems like an ok solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/sys/block/sdX/device/model` contains the device it's booting off. In my case: `Samsung SSD 850`.

You could `grep` it for `USB` for example. Won't be too accurate of course, but should work in most cases :)